# I can't get right url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i need your help.
I have an home button (it exactly is ) in masterpage use for all aspx. Pages is my folder name (it containts my aspx webpages) and it has an "Admin" folder inside (it containts my admin page). It works in all of pages except admin page. when I clicked "Home" from admin page I got "The resource cannot be found." error, and the Url in web browser's address bar is "localhost/Pages/Pages/Home"
I don't know why i get two "Pages" in the Url.
help me please

```
table>
<tr>
    <td width="700px">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="../Pages/Home.aspx">Trang chủ</a> </li>
            <li class="Parent">Sản Phẩm
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../Pages/DienThoai.aspx">Điện thoại</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="../Pages/MayTinhBang.aspx">Máy tính bảng</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="../Pages/PhuKien.aspx">Phụ kiện</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Giới thiệu</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Góp Ý</a> </li>
            <li><a href="../Pages/DangNhap.aspx">Đăng nhập</a> </li>
            <li><a href="../Pages/DangKi.aspx">Đăng kí</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td width="300px">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperQuantri" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"
                        NavigateUrl="~/HienThi/ThongTin.aspx">Thông tin</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperThoat" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"
                        Visible="False" NavigateUrl="~/HienThi/Thoat.aspx">Thoát</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you please post an example of your markup with the Home button on it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have some relative pathing issues with your links. This gets particularly tricky when you're using master/child pages or template controls in a site where you have various depths of folders.

Since you're using web controls, try renaming your links using the following format:

```
~/Pages/Admin/Default.aspx
```

The ~/ directive will tell ASP.Net to build the path of the link from the root of the site, so no matter which page the control resides on, it will generate the proper link.